# How can I dynamically create the source for a frame using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

Suppose I have one html page with frames. The left frame is simply a list of links, which will be displayed in the right frame. Is it possible, using javascript, to generate the contents of the left frame when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parent.frameName.document.body would be the body-element of that frame, you can either use DOM-methods ( .createElement, .appendChild, .insertBefore) or .innerHTML to populate the frame with content.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You can use javascript's `document.write()` or (as I prefer to) keep an empty container (DIV) on the left frame and inject your HTML into its `innerHTML` property (also via javascript).